# How can I import a PowerShell module inside a GitHub workflow from another repository?

Tags: powershell, github-actions

Let's say there is a repository with `cool-module.psm1`. I have another repository with a GitHub workflow and I have this step inside a job:

```
- name: Use the function from the cool-module
  shell: pwsh
  run: |
    FunctionFromCoolModule -param1 coolparameter
```

This will not work since I have to import the `cool-module.psm1`. How can I do that? Locally it's clear that I can use `Import-Module` and a path, but how can I import from another repository?

Comment: You could ```git clone``` the other repo into a temp folder on the Actions Runner as a step prior to running your PowerShell script and then ```Import-Module``` from the temp folder…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a repository and package source, which is done with `Register-PSRepository` and `Register-PackageSource`. The steps in the workflow below show the registration of a private NuGet package source and module installation. I'd expect that you would just want to omit the credentials when registering a public source.

```
jobs:
    publish:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Add cool-module
            shell: pwsh
            run: |-
              $user = "${{ env.nugetSourceUser }}"
              $token = "${{ env.nugetSourceKey }}"
              $feed = "${{ env.nugetSourceUrl }}"
              $repositoryName = "PrivateRepository"

              $tokenAsSecureString = "$token" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
              $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $tokenAsSecureString )

              ## Package Source name - (arbitrary and unrelated to repository name)
              $packageSourceName = "$($repositoryName)PackageSource"

              ## Force TLS1.2
              [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

              $registerArgs = @{
                  Name                        = $repositoryName
                  SourceLocation              = $feed
                  PublishLocation             = $feed
                  InstallationPolicy          = 'Trusted'
                  Credential                  = $creds
              }

              Register-PSRepository @registerArgs

              Register-PackageSource `
                  -Name $packageSourceName `
                  -Location $feed `
                  -ProviderName NuGet `
                  -SkipValidate

              Install-Module -Name "cool-module" -Repository $repositoryName
```

That's the happy path. In my experience, this will not work when your module is published to GitHub Packages. Maybe there's a better way to address this incompatibility, but I've settled on downloading the module package directly with `nuget`, and installing the from a local repository. Here's that workflow.

```
jobs:
    publish:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
          actions: read
          packages: write
        steps:
          - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
            with:
              nuget-version: '5.x'
          - name: Add private Nuget source
            shell: pwsh
            run: |-
              $user = "${{ env.nugetSourceUser }}"
              $token = "${{ env.nugetSourceKey }}"
              $feed = "${{ env.nugetSourceUrl }}"
              $packageSourceName = "PrivateNugetSource"

              ## Add the package source
              nuget sources add `
                -Name $packageSourceName `
                -UserName $user `
                -Password $token `
                -Source $feed `
                -Verbosity detailed `
                -StorePasswordInClearText

              ## Set the API key
              nuget setapikey $token -Source $feed

              ## Create a directory for local repository
              mkdir ./__modules

              ## Register the local repository
              Register-PSRepository `
                -Name 'localRepository' `
                -SourceLocation ./__modules `
                -InstallationPolicy Trusted 

          - name: Install PowerShell module
            shell: pwsh
            run: |-

              ## Install the package containing the module to the local repository
              nuget install "cool-module" `
                -DirectDownload `
                -OutputDirectory ./__modules `
                -Source ${{ env.nugetSourceUrl }} `
                -Verbosity detailed

              ## Install the module from the local repository
              Install-Module -Name "cool-module" -Repository 'localRepository'
```